# Button stretches with constraints - constraint layout, android

Tags: android

So I've been trying to make a constraint UI that will change accordingly to the users screen size. Most of the stuff I saw is to use guide lines and make the width 0... But when I do that the button stretches:

What it should look like:
[image]

What it looks like:
[image]

here is the important part of my xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.04"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/addTask2" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.96"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/addProjectTitle"
    />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.45"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/createMoreTasks"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="142dp"
    android:background="@drawable/plus_black_tiny"
    android:tag="newProjectButton"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    app:backgroundTint="@null"
    app:cornerRadius="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline3"
    />
```

and here is the xml for  the style "plus_black_tiny":

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="43dp"
    android:width="380dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#E0E0E0"
        android:fillAlpha="0.5"
    android:pathData="M0,24h24V0H0z"/>
    <path
        android:fillColor="#000"
        android:pathData="M16,11H12V8H11.9V11H11.5V11.9H11.9V15H12V11.9H12.4V11Z" />
</vector>
```

how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I am stupid.
In my code, I wrote this line:

```
getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * 2), (int) (height * 0.85));
```

**Option 1:**
To fix my problem I only need to not multiply the width at all and then the button won't strech:

```
getWindow().setLayout(width, (int) (height * 0.85));
```

**Option 2:**
Because I realized that the button is twice its size, I can just reduce the guideLines by half and then the button will be in place:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.02"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/addTask2" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.475"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/addProjectTitle"
        />
```